# How to show all searched results in pdf in a glance?

Tags: pdf, search, evince

In evince, when searching some text in a pdf file, the result will be displayed one by one by hitting "next" or "previous" button.

I wonder if it is possible to glance at once all found results with a little context for each in either evince or other software? I remember adobe acrobat seems to be able to do this, and djview can also do the same for djvu files.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no PDF reader on Linux that offers this capability as a part of its inbuilt toolset. However, you can always use an external desktop search engine such as [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) to gain an overview of search term instances within a PDF document.

Recoll's newest releases come with a nifty snippet window that does exactly what you're looking for:

[image]

And, what's more, clicking on one of the page numbers will immediately direct you to the relevant part of the document and pass the search term to the document viewer.

**Note**: this will only work if you use Recoll coupled with a PDF viewer that is capable of being passed page numbers and search terms from the command line. Ubuntu's default PDF viewer, evince, can do that. Others, such as KDE's Okular can't at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Evince 3.10.3, available in Ubuntu 14.04, supports this feature

Answer (score 1):

You could use console tools to achieve this (see the second comment on [this page](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/searching-pdf-files-grep)):

```
$ pdftotext yourPdfFile.pdf -| grep yourSearchString
```

Comment: Thanks! That will lose the information of which page each result is from.

Comment: oops - you're right, i didn't consider that point.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a purpose of giving like that it is the PDF(PRINTABLE DOCUMENT FORMAT) is generally consists of large volume of data so instead of finding all the pages and displaying the results may take time and for some documents it may fail to run so its is better to display in current page. and actually i think there is no option like that for PDF

Comment: That is not convenient sometimes though. adobe acrobat is able to do this for pdf files, and djview can also do the same for djvu files.

Comment: PDF stands for *Portable* Document Format.